# Slicy every nth element, not beginnint with the first

Tags: python, list, slice

How can I elegantly separate a python list into two, so that the second one has every nth element of the first one, and these sliced elements are removed from the first list? **The slicing should not begin with the first element!**

Example:

```
split_data([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
```

should return
`([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14], [5,10,15])`

Thank you :)

Edit:
For the part of selecting every nth element, I tried the following:

```
test = data[::5]
train = data
del data[::5]
return (train, test)
```

this however would only return `([2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, ...], [1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26])` for `split_data(list(range(1, 30)))`.
With *elegant* I wanted to express that I wanted to avoid using a for-loop to iterate over the list ;)

Comment: What have you tried already that "isn't elegant"?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far and why it doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have edited my post.

Comment: by the way: from your `train`/`test` names it seems you are doing a classification/ML stuff. Then you are/should be probably using numpy arrays or pandas dataframes or something similar and not lists. This way it can be done more elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can take advantage of `list.pop()` which removes an element by index and also returns it. So your original list will not contain those numbers and by creating a new list with the popped items you can have your second list.</s>

```py
def split(l,n):
    return (l, [l.pop(i) for i in range(n, len(l), n)])

>>>l = list(range(1,16))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

>>>split(l,4)
([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14], [5, 10, 15])
```

This will mutate the list passed as argument. If you want your function to leave it as is, simply add `l=list(l)` before messing with `l`.

**Thanks to @crazyvalues this answer is not valid as `list.pop()` decreases the length of the list while iterating, eventually resulting in indices being out of bounds.**

However, using `numpy` or `pandas` one can still solve the same problem "elegantly":

- numpy:

```py
def slice_numpy(l, n):
    l = np.array(l) 
    mask = list(range(n-1,len(l),n))
    return np.delete(l, mask), l[mask]
    # note that `len` and `delete` will work as expected on 1D arrays. if you have a 2D dataset you need to modify them accordingly
```

- pandas

```py
def slice_pandas(l, n):
    l = pd.Series(l)
    mask = list(range(n-1,len(l),n))
    return l.drop(mask), l[mask]
```

- Example:

```py
>>> l = list(range(1, 16))
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>>
>>>
>>> train, test = slice_numpy(l, 5)
>>> train
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11, 12, 13, 14])
>>> test
array([ 5, 10, 15])
>>>
>>>
>>> train, test = slice_pandas(l, 5)
>>> train
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
10    11
11    12
12    13
13    14
dtype: int64
>>> test
4      5
9     10
14    15
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I did not know about this functionality of `pop()` :)

Comment: Using `pop()` does work in the example you presented, but with lists with an (even slightly) bigger length, the code throws an execution, because when we pop out elements of the list, we decrease its size, and sooner or later, we will try to access indexes that aren't in the list anymore.

Comment: This is so true. I am updating my answer

Comment: have a look now

Comment: That is a very interesting approach. And it works fine ;)
Thank you once again